# Casting a datagridview

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, datagridview, .net-3.5, c#-3.0

I have the following code:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
{
    textBox1.Text += row.Cells[1].Value;
}
```

You can probably tell that I am trying to loop through a particular column based on the selected rows of the dataGridView.  But it's giving me an error on the following line:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
```

The error is:

```
Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
```

or, if you need to get at the row from the selected cells:

```
foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
{
   DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[cell.RowIndex];
   ..
}
```

In your case the first solution seems to be right, (just like Aaron wrote it.)

**Note** that both solutions have one or two problems:

The first solution will not get the natural sort order, unless the users take care to follow the weird rules of windows selections..

Use this to solve that problem:

```
var selectedRowsOrdered = DGV.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().OrderBy(c => c.Index);

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in selectedRowsOrdered ) textBox1.Text += row[1].Value;
```

In the second solution, using the `SelectedCells` collection, you in addition also may have duplicates.

Use this little `Linq` to get rid of them as well:

```
var selectedRowsOrdered = DGV.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                         .Select(c => c).OrderBy(c => c.RowIndex).GroupBy(c => c);

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in selectedRowsOrdered ) textBox1.Text += row[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your foreach, you are trying to create a DataGridViewRow but asking for it from a collection of DataGridViewCell, which is why you are getting the error. Instead use DataGridViewCell in the foreach and then use the cell to get to the row:

```
foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
    textBox1.Text += cell.OwningRow.Cells[1].Value;
}
```